# "Little"/"Less' instead of "not a lot"

Tags: word-choice

> We are getting **very little** orders these days.
>
> We are getting **very less** orders these days.

What sounds likely a replacement for "we're not getting a lot of orders these days."

Comment: Neither. *We are getting very **few** orders these days*.

Answer (score 0):

"Very little" can only be used with non-count nouns, like "very little help" or "very little involvement" or "very little milk in my coffee".

"Orders" is a countable noun. (Usually if a noun is plural, it will be countable, because plural means that there is more than one.)

With countable nouns, you can use the words "few" and "fewer", as in these examples:
 "we are getting few orders", "we are getting very few orders", "we are getting fewer orders", "we are getting many fewer orders", "we are getting very many fewer orders".

As to "We are getting less orders than we were before": using "less" with a countable noun will be rejected by some, who insist on "fewer orders", even though "less" is commonly used in informal speech.
See the usage note in the American Heritage dictionary definition of "less": 
[AHD "less"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=less)

Finally, "less" is the comparative form of "little". You can't use "very" with a comparative adjective directly, but you can say "much less" or "very much less".

Comment: And "less" can be used only when we specify "less than what", right? It can't simply be "We're getting less orders", or will the last part be assumed? I mean doesn't the sentence sound incomplete without including the explanation "less than what", which is not the case with "few"?

Comment: Actually, if not specified, the comparison will be taken to be "less than we were before", though a listener can certainly ask "Less than what?". You are correct that "few" is not a comparative.

Comment: And if someone has filled a glass too much (to the brim), that the water's spilling, what sounds natural instead of "don't fill it up that much": "Fill it a **little less** than that." or "Fill it a **little lower** than that."

Comment: Do you mean, saying "He is no more." to mean that someone is deceased? That would would be a figurative or poetic usage. For the glass example, you might say "Don't overfill it." Of your two suggestions, "a little less" is more idiomatic.

Comment: So is "fill it up a little less" likely to be used? Or should it be "fill it up a little less than that"? (Comparison)

Comment: Just  "Don't spill it!". or "Don't overfill it!" or "Not THAT much, please!" or "Whoa, take it easy!".  They're all emphatic, because you're talking about spilling something and making a mess. Those expressions are all idiomatic. "Fill it up a little less that that." is grammatically sound but not natural in the situation.